# How to fix the mistake in my collage with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I want to create a collage of 3 x 3 pictures. I want to reuse the code with which I did a 2 x 2 collage, but it's not working. Primarily **I want to understand my mistake**, not get running code (I am aware that there is a solution online here but with a different approach).

Help would be much appreciated, as I am totally new to coding.

```
from PIL import Image    
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (640,480))

width = 213
height = 160

x = 0
y = 0

for im in image_list:
    if (x == 640):
        y = y + height
        x = 0
    im.thumbnail((width, height))
    new_im.paste(im, (x,y))
    x = x + width

new_im.save('collage.png')
```

Comment: When will `x == 640` happen? Print the values of `x` each iteration: 0, 213, 426, 639...not 640.

Comment: Well, I thought 'x == 640' should be reached with the third picture, 3*213 (width)? It works with bigger thumbnails, 2*320, than I get a collage of 2 x 2. That is what is vexing me.

Comment: 3*213 = 639, not 640. 640 is not divisible by 3.

Comment: What you *should* do IMO is create the new image to be the size `(width*3, height*3)`, that way it will be the exact size of your collage and then check `if x == width*3:`.

Comment: Silly me. Works perfectly fine with `x >= 639`. Can't believe I did not spot that mistake by myself.
But I will give your solution a try as well. Thanks a million!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then. Otherwise looks good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always be sure to print your values as a first step for debugging. A simple

```
print(x, y)
```

at the bottom of your loop would have saved you the trouble. The variable `x` only gets updated by 213 each time in this case, which isn't a multiple of 640.

If you want your collage to be `NxM` in general then simply take the width and height to be `width/N` and `height/M` and round to integers. Then check whenever `x >= width*N` to advance `y`.